# Yum failing "Transaction Check" when updating

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

I'm trying to update my Cent OS 5.2 system using `yum`. But I've been getting this error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/man/man1/pcregrep.1.gz from install of pcre-8.02-1.jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/pcretest.1.gz from install of pcre-8.02-1.jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.i386
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.50-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.3.i386
```

I can go through and install any package that doesn't require updating mysql.

I've tried `yum clean all`

I must admit I know only enough to get in trouble when it comes to Linux, but it seems to me yum is trying to update mysql to 5.1.x but can't.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the errors, you'll notice that the existing packages are i386, and the other packages are x86_64. These archs can usually live side-by-side, *when they have the same version and release*. Either find x86_64 or i386 packages that have the same version and release as the other, or remove the i386 packages altogether.

Comment: Any guidance on removing the i386 versions of mysql?

Comment: `rpm -e` or `yum remove`.